# pam cannot access variable created within function

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I discovered a very peculiar problem when writing a function using the function `pam()` from the `cluster` package. The code below is a strongly reduced version of the original function that demonstrates the problem:

```
library(cluster)
Dat=array(data=runif(10*2*20, 0, 50), dim=c(10, 2, 20))
Groups=c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10))
#K=3

Test<-function (Dat, Groups, K=3) {
#Transform groups
Groups<-as.factor(Groups)

#Decompose data into Euclidean space
Eucl.Coord<-t(matrix(Dat, (dim(Dat)[1])*2, dim(Dat)[3]))

#Define colour-coding
ColSet<-rainbow(length(levels(Groups)))
Col<-ColSet[match(Groups, levels(Groups))]

#Perform partitional clustering
KMeans<-pam(dist(Eucl.Coord), k=K)
Class<-length(which(KMeans$clustering==as.numeric(Groups)))/length(Groups)
plot(KMeans, which.plot=1, shade=TRUE, col.p=Col, col.txt=Col,   col.clus="grey90", main=paste("Correct classification: ", round(Class*100, digits=2), "%", sep=""))
}

Test(Dat=Dat, Groups=Groups, K=3)
```

Now, the problem is the following: When I load `Test()` as a function and try to run it, I get the error message

> Error in as.matrix(x) : object 'Eucl.Coord' not found Error in
>   clusplot.partition(x, stand = stand, lines = lines, shade = shade,  : 
>   no diss nor data found, nor the original argument of pam(x =
>   dist(Eucl.Coord), k = K)

This seems to imply that `pam()` wants to use an object (`Eucl.Coord`) that is not there. But here is the curious thing: When you run the code within the function by hand, all is well. `Eucl.Coord` is created and used by `pam()` correctly. If after a manual run you want to use the function again it also works, because `pam()` then uses the `Eucl.Coord` in the global variable space that have been created during the initial run. Close R and try to run the function again, and it does not work anymore because `Eucl.Coord` does not exist in the global space anymore.

I know that `Eucl.Coord` is set up correctly, because in the real function other code segments use it as well without any problems. It is as if `pam()`, and only `pam()`, cannot access an object that was created within the function. I have never seen such behaviour before. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Actually the error comes in `plot`. The `pam` function is executed (you can check it by modifying your `Test` function and commenting the `plot` line). The issue apparently is in `plot.partition`.

Comment: It seems that the `plot` method relies on the `diss` component of the `pam` object to work. Call `pam` with `keep.diss=TRUE`.

Comment: @nicola Thank you, that was actually it. If you want to post your comment as answer I can accept it.